# Adding a label with geom_text correctly places all labels but one for a grouped variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-text

I want to add group labels to my graph, but the first letter is misplaced a little bit to the right. What is wrong here?

[image: Image of graph]

```
plot <- ggplot(data=df_sub, aes(y=fluo_roots, x=genotype)) +
               geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, lwd=0.2) +                                       
               geom_point(size=0.7, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0)) +
               xlab("") +
               ylab("Fluorescent root number per explant") +
               ggtitle("") +
               theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
                     panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey80", linetype = "dashed"),
                     axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(size=7),
                     axis.text.y = element_text(size=7),
                     axis.title.y = element_text(size=8))
plot
plot + geom_text(data=df_sub.summarized,
                 aes(x = genotype,
                     y = Max_root, 
                     label = .group))
```

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a short sample of your data. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of `dput(df_sub)` (preferred) or in tab delimited form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most probably the problem stems from that the labels come from a different dataset than the rest of the plot, but without seeing a sample of your data it is hard to say how to correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your replys. As I was editing my question giving futher code, I saw that my letter labels were "   c", "  b ", " a  " and" ab ". After deleting the spaces, everything looks fine.